# Getting Text from a textbox and putting it into another list

Tags: c#, html, string, visual-c++, textbox

just liked to say thanks to those taking time to read this. So basically lets say i have a textbox (in c++ clr) and its multiline and has a bunch of stuff lets say it has:

```
Apples
Bananas
Oranges
Peaches
```

Now i have another textbox. I am using a WebBrowser view because html is easy to change just certain colors and now I want to redisplay the apples and other things. some thing like:

```
Fruits are:
Apples 
Bananas
and so on...
```

But I do not know how many strings will be in the textbox. So what ive decided to do is:

```
System::String^ l1;
System::String^ l2;
System::String^ l3;
System::String^ l4;
System::String^ l5;
System::String^ l6;
//and so on...
WebBrowser1->DocumentText = "Fruits are: <br>";
if(l1){
    WebBrowser1->DocumentText = l1 + "<br>";
    if(l2){
         WebBrowser1->DocumentText = l2 + "<br>"
         if(l3){
              WebBrowser1->DocumentText = l3 + "<br>"
           //and so on
         }
    }
}
```

Im just wondering if theres a better way to do this. Because i have up to l20 and i want the program to support as much as possible.

PS: i will get the data values of l1 in like somewhere before the if statements
PSS: i placed the l2 inside l1 and l3 inside l2... because otherwise l2 would be l1 when parsing the original text box. 
PSSS: I think there is something wrong with the code too because i gave l1 a value and it wasnt displaying properly.

Comment: Side note: going with C# instead of managed C++ would give you way more samples/people who know answers... In mean time reading about arrays may help.

Comment: +Alexei Levenkov alright thanks, i added C# to the tags

Answer (score 0):

A better way, in any language, is to use an array instead of a bunch of different variables, and some loop to iterate over elements of that array.

Comment: alright, thanks so maybe something like `string l[100]` and then like a `for loop` with `int i` and just loop and check each string and write it, but not all the parts of the string will be full so do i just check with like an `if statement` and then `break` from the `for loop`?